# How to use pandas resample using 'day of year' data (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, resampling

My pandas array looks like this...

```
     DOY Value
0      5  5118
1     10  5098
2     15  5153
```

I've been trying to resample my data and fill in the gaps using pandas resample function. My worry is that since I'm trying to resample without using direct datetime values, I won't be able to resample my data.

My attempt to solve this was using the following line of code but got an error saying I was using Range Index. Perhaps I need to use Period Index somehow, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

```
inter.resample('1D').mean().interpolate()
```

Here's my intended result

```
     DOY Value
0      5  5118
1      6  5114
2      7  5110
3      8  5106
4      9  5102
5     10  5098
:      :    :
10    15  5153
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `to_datetime`, perform the `resample` and then drop the unwanted column:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DOY"].astype(str),format="%j")
output = df.resample("D", on="date").last().drop("date", axis=1).interpolate().reset_index(drop=True)

>>> output
     DOY   Value
0    5.0  5118.0
1    6.0  5114.0
2    7.0  5110.0
3    8.0  5106.0
4    9.0  5102.0
5   10.0  5098.0
6   11.0  5109.0
7   12.0  5120.0
8   13.0  5131.0
9   14.0  5142.0
10  15.0  5153.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`pd.DataFrame.interpolate` works on the index.  So let's start with setting an appropriate index and then a new one over which we will interpolate.

```
d0 = df.set_index('DOY')
idx = pd.RangeIndex(d0.index.min(), d0.index.max()+1, name='DOY')

d0.reindex(idx).interpolate().reset_index()

      DOY   Value
0       5  5118.0
1       6  5114.0
2       7  5110.0
3       8  5106.0
4       9  5102.0
5      10  5098.0
6      11  5109.0
7      12  5120.0
8      13  5131.0
9      14  5142.0
10     15  5153.0
```